# rails 4 migration one person multiple addresses: ActiveRecord error STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a person model that i want to connect to multiple addresses (main_address, work_address etc.)

In app/models/person.rb:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :main_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :main_address_id
  belongs_to :work_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :work_address_id
  belongs_to :invoice_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :invoice_address_id
  belongs_to :further_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :further_address_id

end
```

And an address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

address migration:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :street
      t.string :zip
      t.string :city
      t.string :country
      t.string :lockbox
      t.string :type
      t.references :person, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/main_address.rb:

```
class MainAddress < Address
end
```

When i try to save an address in rails console (the person with id 1 was already created):

```
2.2.1 (main):0 > main_address = Address.create(type: "main_address", street: "Schumannstr.15", zip: "D-53113", city: "Bonn", country: "Germany", person_id: 1)
```

I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: main_address is not a subclass of Address
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a class defined for each of the main_address, work_address, etc types?

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention them. i updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a problem with your belongs_to associations. It seems to me that an address belong to a person, and a person has many addresses. If conceptually this does not represent your requirements then the rest of this answer will need to be adapted.

Also, in the original example you are specifying foreign keys that don't exist as columns in the addresses table. Each address will just be referred to through its *id* and *type* pair.

I would expect this type of code to work:

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :addresses 
end

# app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :person     
end

# app/models/main_address.rb
class MainAddress < Address
end
```

The *type* column in your table should trigger STI, allowing you to do something like:

```
person = Person.create(...)
person.addresses.create(street: "Schumannstr.15", zip: "D-53113", city: "Bonn", country: "Germany")
```

Hopefully this will work for you. If not, feel free to edit or comment as needed.